# LinQ : when query will be executed

Tags: c#-3.0

As per this  link :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx

```
namespace Linq
{
    class IntroToLINQ
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // The Three Parts of a LINQ Query: 
            //  1. Data source. 
            int[] numbers = new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

            // 2. Query creation. 
            // numQuery is an IEnumerable<int> 
            var numQuery =
                from num in numbers
                where (num % 2) == 0
                select num;

            // 3. Query execution. 
            foreach (int num in numQuery)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,1} ", num);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It states that query will not be exeucted , until data is iterated through foreach. But when I debugged , the data memeber of var(resultviews) contains the result values before the execution of foreach. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your debugger is executing the query for you.

Linq is using something that is called Deferred Execution. Here is a good blog post that explains it: [LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

When you first execute the iterator, the query is processed and executed (in memory, to a database or in another way). Your debugger will do this for you.

Take for example the following code (you can paste this in a Console Application):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();

            var filteredNumbers = from n in numbers
                                  where n > 50
                                  select n;

            Debugger.Break();

            foreach(int f in filteredNumbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When you look at `filteredNumbers` on the Debugger.Break() statement you will see the following:

[image: Debug view of Linq Enumerable]

The Results View options has the Value: "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable". And that's what's happening in the Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the variable with the debugger, Visual Studio is executing the iterator. That's why you see the results.

It's for the same reason that you should not put `i++` in the watch window, because the code is actually executed.